# MemoryError , Create Pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

my code is this :

```
pd.DataFrame(testMatrix, index = [0 for x in range(25000)], columns = testFeatureNames)
```

by running this code this error is display:

MemoryError

testMatrix has 25000 rows and 56000 columns!

how can i fix this?

Comment: Is `testMatrix` sparse?

Comment: not all but yes!

Comment: You can use `pd.SparseDataFrame` then.

Comment: in this time show this error: Killed

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: my RAM is 6 GB.